# Run JavaScript in clean chrome/puppeteer context

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I am attempting to run JavaScript on a page context with content scraping as the goal. With puppeteer, I can easily call `evaluate()` and run a piece of JavaScript inside the context of the page. So I basically just evaluate a `document.querySelector` on the page:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'file:///C:/Users/roel/puppettest/index.html';

puppeteer.launch({headless: false}).then(async browser => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
    const value = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div').textContent);
    if (value === 'Hello') {
        console.log('Works');
    } else {
        console.log('Nope :-(');
    }
});
```

And this is the page that I referred to:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div>Hello</div>
        <script>
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.textContent = 'Whooh!';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
            document.querySelector = null;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So here's the problem: The code I evaluated runs a `document.querySelector`, but the page that I loaded set that to `null`. Chaos ensues. So... **I want to ensure that the JavaScript that I run is ran on a clean context**.

#### First Idea:

I can just retrieve the generated HTML and create a new JavaScript context around the DOM. Run a `page.content()` to retrieve the HTML and... Oh, it's not the current HTML, it's the initial HTML (e.g. the `document.createElement()` didn't execute). Running a `page.evaluate(() => document.body.innerHTML)` would work assuming the page didn't add a `Object.defineProperty` on `body` property of `document`. But there is no such guarantee. Is there a way to retrieve the current HTML without touching the JS context?

#### Second Idea:

Chrome extensions run in their own JavaScript context with access to the DOM, and only the DOM. Which is exactly what I'm after. Looking over the `puppeteer` documentation, there is no indication to creating such a context within puppeteer itself. Or is there and I missed it?

...

So how do I go about getting a clean JS context to run queries against?

**EDIT** I read the output of `.content()` wrong. The HTML is included. So, the first idea does work. I'm still curious if the second idea is achieveable as it is much preferred.

Comment: Is disabling javascript is an option for you? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetjavascriptenabledenabled

Comment: @Everettss No, the JS on the page is needed to construct the DOM as it should be. Disabling it after, and running evaluation code, works -- but that's already when functions in the context may have been altered.

Comment: you could retrieve the html content as a string after evaluate "window.document.children[0].innerHTML", remove all scripts and parse it

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a Puppeteer API for achieving #2. Do you want to convert your first idea to an answer and mark that as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.content()` to retrieve the HTML at the current point in time. The pre-edit question wrongly assumed that `.content()` returned the original. Running this resulting HTML into `jsdom` allows you to execute JS on the DOM without being affected by the original page.